Maximal-type inequality for a Borel probability measure supported on a subset of $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$
Let $\mu$ be a Borel probability measure on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ for $d\ge 1$ which is moreover supported on the unit sphere
$$S=\{\phi\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d): \| \phi\|_{ L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)}=1\}.$$
Let us denote
$$(f,g) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} fg\,dx$$
and $\hat{f}$ is the Fourier transform on $\mathbb{R}^d$.
Under which conditions on $\mu$, if any, can we guarantee that for any $k\ge 1$.
\begin{aligned}
A_k\equiv \sup_{\psi,\|\psi\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d)}=1} \int_S  |(\psi, \hat{\phi})|^{2k}d\mu(\phi)&\le C_k \int_S\sup_{\psi,\|\psi\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d)}=1}  |(\psi, \hat{\phi})|^{2k} d\mu(\phi)?
\end{aligned}
Note that the RHS can be written as
$$\int_S \left(\sup_{\psi,\|\psi\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d)}=1}  |(\psi, \hat{\phi})|\right)^{2k}d\mu(\phi)=\int_S \| \hat{\phi}\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)}^{2k}d\mu(\phi)$$
by duality.
Assume that $A_k$ is well-defined for each $k\ge 1$ and in fact $A_k\le C \varepsilon^{2k}$ for some $C, \varepsilon>0$ and all $k\ge 1$ if that is helpful.
Note: this question came up in my study of the Gross-Pitaevski hierarchy for infinitely many bosons.

Why the downvote? I am definitely open to editing the question given suggestions to improve it.

The Fourier transform is isometry on $L^2(\Bbb R^d)$. Should we better replace $\hat\phi$ by $\phi$?

I actually want $\hat{\phi}$ since I am interested for various reason in studying the Gross-Pitaevksi hierarchy with initial data lying in some tensorized version of the space $\mathcal{F}L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$, one of them being that the space is an algebra.

The reason we consider a measure supported on $L^2$ comes from a quantum de Finetti theorem which tells us that for a natural initial datum, it may be written as the convex combination of tensorized states with respect to exactly a Borel measure supported on $S$.
